# Combining COUNTIFS with a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

I have looked through other posts on here and cannot find the solution I need.

I am currently using this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Tracking!$F$3:$XA$3,$F1,Tracking!$F4:$XA4,"~*")
```

This is counting all the * values that match to the reference "Attainment" (This is cell F1), but is relying on my 2 worksheets to have the people listed in exactly the same order. What I really want is the countif to calculate based on matching the person ID.

I have 2 sheets that use a unique ID for each person. I want to be able to match this ID and then run the countif, so in essence combine a VLOOKUP with the COUNTIFS. I did try adding another criteraia to the COUNTIFS but this doesn't seem to work. No IDs are repeated in either sheet. The unique ID defines each row and the row holds a very large amount of grade data for the person.

Sample Data
[image: This is my grading data]

[image: This is my summary sheet with COUNTIFS]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54149968/edit) to give us sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: Pictures of data now added @cybernetic.nomad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this using this formula in F3

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Tracking!"&MATCH(A3,Tracking!$A:$A,0)&":"&MATCH(A3,Tracking!$A:$A,0)),"*~*")
```

This is using the row number of the match to COUNTIFS any cells with a `*` in that row.

Comment: I am getting a circular reference with this formula - does it need to include my sheet name somewhere?

Comment: Thank you so much Tate - this worked like a dream. Genius!

Comment: Sorry to ask for additional help, but I also need to be able to match 3 criteria to do another countif with this data. I need it to match the studentID, if the data contained in Tracking!F3:XA3 matches to the word in Sheet1!X2 and only count if the result is "WB. Is this possible?

Comment: I have tried the following, but it isn't working:

=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Tracking!"&MATCH($A3,Tracking!$A:$A,0)&":"&MATCH($A3,Tracking!$A:$A,0)),X$2,Tracking!F:XA,"WB")